# At what value of $x$ does the function$ f(x)=...$ intersect its oblique asymtote?

Tags: functions

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmbTM.png)

With long division, I get the $x+5$ and $-x+3$ remainder. What should I do after that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)$ is of the form $f(x)=x+5+\epsilon(x)$, where $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\epsilon(x)\to0$. Hence, $y=x+5$ is the oblique asymptote of $f$. Next, you need to solve $f(x)=x+5$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Is answer D? Also, I'm bad with infinite limits. Can you explain it in more details? From what I understand, you can avoid using long division. Is it right?

Comment: You need to solve $x+5-\frac{x-3}{x^{2}-1}=x+5$, that is, $-\frac{x-3}{x^{2}-1}=0$. For which $x$ is this equality satisfied? Considering the limit, you may compute it as follows: $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\epsilon(x)=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} -\frac{x-3}{x^{2}-1}=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} -\frac{x}{x^{2}}=\lim_{x\to\pm\infty} -\frac1x=0$.

Comment: Please take a look at [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508).